# How to automatically move mail into appropriate folders - Outlook for Mac 2011

Tags: macos, microsoft-outlook-2011, rules

Is there anyway to have emails automatically placed into folders where the original email resides?

Situation: I sort my emails into various folders based on clients. However, when a new email comes in that was a reply to a previous it goes to my inbox versus going into the client folder. I know the typical answer is "just create a rule for that client". The problem with that is my clients change often, and creating a new rule that often is infeasible.

I was hoping there might be some way to have a "follow source email" option. That way, **when I move email A into folder X, all subsequent replies to email A will automatically be placed in folder X.**

Any ideas?